# Background-size : Cover - Firefox issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use `background-size : cover` in my page, and it seems to be working correctly on all browsers except firefox (I haven't checked IE yet...but I want to fix the firefox issue for now).

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdAcX/1/)

Any idea why it's not working in firefox? Usually, `background-size : cover` works in Firefox. It seems to be having an issue with the jQuery script in the page. But it works great in Safari and Chrome.

Try resizing the browser window, you'll see what I mean.

Thank you!

Comment: it looks same in firefox and chrome, what is not working?

Comment: If you resize the window, you'll see the "background-size: cover" won't work in firefox. It is supposed to shrink proportionally.

Comment: it is shrinking proportionally, which version of firefox are you using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 14.0.1 and it's not working for me

Comment: sorry I don't see any issue, but ya am using 10.2 so..

Comment: Weird. I even tested it with BrowserStack...and it's not working in Firefox 10 either...Thanks though for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

`$(this).css('background','url(' + preloadArr[currImg++%preloadArr.length].src +') top center no-repeat');`

to

`$(this).css('background-image','url(' + preloadArr[currImg++%preloadArr.length].src +')');`

and then set background-position and background-repeat accordingly.

When you set the `background` attribute FF overwrites the `background-size` attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/bdAcX/2/

Comment: Bah, you updated at the same time I added a fixed fiddle too. ;)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks guys! Didn't know that FF overwrites the background-size attribute in these cases...THanks again

Comment: I was faster - you set the attributes nicer ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bdAcX/4/ - the closing brackets for the document ready function were missing in @MattHuggins' example

Comment: Thanks a lot. Everything's fine now :)